# How to delete element from xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, element

I have list of people with some data called Person. I would like to delete selected person based on its name (in this example).

That's my code which saves list of Persons to an XML file:

```
        string path = "E:\\test.xml";
        var list = new List<Person>();
        list.Add(new Person { Name = "Tom", Value = 40 });
        list.Add(new Person { Name = "John", Value = 33 });
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
        var writer = new StreamWriter(path);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
        writer.Close();
```

Now i would like to delete Person object John and all data tied with this object from an xml file.

I tried few things, but none of them seemed to work. I would like to find out how to this using this simple example which will help me to step ahead.

Kind Regards,
Tamara

Comment: See the above. Your best bet is creating a 'XmlDocument' object out of your file and using it's methods to locate said node and delete said node, then save over the previous file'

Comment: I would recommend `XDocument` over the older `XmlDocument` but either will work.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been mentioned in the comments, you need to read the XML file into an XDocument object. Once the XDocument has been created, you can work with the elements inside that XDocument. Below is how you would remove the element where the Value is "John"

```
 var xml = File.ReadAllText(path);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            doc.Descendants().Elements("Person")
                .Where(x => x.Element("Name")?.Value == "John")
                .Remove();
            var result = doc.ToString();
```